# Teamspeak hierarchy permission configuration

Tags: permissions, grouping, teamspeak

I'm trying to configure my teamspeak server and I don't know how to do some things, so I'm asking help to configure it... here is what i wanted to do:

I have some categories like 'Minecraft' or 'Planetside 2' or 'Devlopment' and each categorie contain some channel and sub channel. which lead to something like that:

[image]

Then about users :

- First, there's me: the admin.
- Then I want to be able to put some people in a 'Moderator' group
- Me and moderators can define some people as 'Categorie leader'. for example, I can put people A to be a 'Minecraft Category leader'
- A Categorie leader can define who is in his categorie (of course moderator and admin can also), for instance: My Minecraft categorie leader A can put people B to be a Minecraft Player. But a Minecraft Categorie leader can't put People C as a 'Planetside 2 player'.

This configuration is show on this picture:

[image]

Then about the channel !

I will take the example of the Planetside 2 Categorie :

I will have 2 channels in the categorie : the first one will allow only Planetside 2 player, Planetside 2 leader and admin to access it. the second one will allow everybody to access.

How can I do that ?

For the moment I didn't try anything, as I don't want to do some mistake that would make it hard ton configure. But I was thinking about channel group, and allow a channel group to access a particular channel. I found some topics on google which make me think it's not that hard.

But then, i don't find anything which can help me to do the part where I want my Categorie leader putting channel groupe only for his categorie.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, unfortunately, this is not possible.

TeamSpeak permission is based on a numeric system, instead of a tree hierarchy system.

In other words, if my value is greater than yours, I have power over you.

So back to your case, the most you can do is a four-level rank, with Admin -> Moderator -> Leader -> Members.

In other words, if your leader made their own member groups, all other leaders can access it (since they got higher power than the member group), which is not something you'd want, but that's the sad reality of it.

Now, to your second question on channel groups, this is doable, just follow the instructions:

1. set all channel's needed_join_power with *a value greater than 0*, also make sure that you set the needed_join_power of the channel you want to exclusively for leaders is higher than that value.
2. set admin and moderator's join_power higher or equals to the value *you set for step 1*.
3. set the **SERVER GROUP** of the default *Member* group's join power to 0
4. set up channel groups with *Leader* and *Member*, both with join_power higher than the value in *step 1*, also make sure *Leader*'s join power is higher than *Member*'s
5. Grant *Leader* with the power to move user

Done. Once this is complete, the leader can move users into their channel and grant the user with the associated channel groups. When the user is assigned with the associated channel group, they can freely move in and out of the channel at free will.